# CSS - shifted menu in Opera

Tags: html, css

I have one problem. I have this web:
[www.keramikadomecek.cz/](http://www.keramikadomecek.cz/)

And in all browser everything is ok. But in Opera the horizontal menu is shifted 20px to the right.

Do you know what's wrong?
Thank you very much and sorry for my English :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using HTML5, which the current HTML parser (Presto) for Opera doesn't fully understand. It's default behavior with unrecognized elements is to immediately close them, which throws your markup/styling off, as you see...

See this link: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto25/html5/

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to mention that the link above is for a somewhat older version of Opera. There are links in the sidebar to updated documentation, so you'd have to find your way to the page matching the version of Opera you're targeting in your testing.

Comment: I don't think this is related to Kryštof's issue. The code is basically HTML4, except for two things new to HTML5: doctype and `<a>` element being the parent node of block element. Both are well supported in all browsers including Opera.

Comment: @duri `<menu>` is an HTML5 tag which only has partial support in Opera. This is actually the sort of behavior Opera exhibits when it encounters elements it doesn't have rules for. And it's not "code," it's markup.

Comment: `<menu>` was defined since HTML 3.2 and behaved like unordered list. HTML5 only defines additional features for `<menu>` (`type` and `label` attributes), but Kryštof doesn't use them. It's totally safe to use `<menu>` this way. Sorry for my confusion in terms "code" and "markup", English is not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;
```

instead of

```
margin-left: -20px;
```

for `menu` in your CSS.

I'd also recommend you setting `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` for `menu`, because your `<menu>` only contains floated elements and they need to be cleared.

Also consider updating jQuery to latest version (not related to this issue).